# Парсинг хеш-таблицы в JSON-ответе

Tags: json, golang

Имеется такой вид *JSON*-ответа:

```json
{
  "success": true,
  "message": "",
  "result": {
    "ETH": {
      "available": "0",
      "freeze": "0"
    },
    "BTC": {
      "available": "0",
      "freeze": "0"
    }
  }
}
```

Пытался парсить это в таком виде:

```golang
type BalancesResponce struct {
    Success bool          `json:"success"`
    Message string        `json:"message"`
    Result  AccBalances   `json:"result"`
}

type AccBalances struct {
    Symbol AccBalance
}

type AccBalance struct {
    Available  string `json:"available"`
    Freeze     string `json:"freeze"`
}

// Происходит запрос к API.
// Получаю ответ таким образом:

var accBalance map[string]interface{}
err = json.Unmarshal(htmlData, &accBalance)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

if accBalance["message"] != "" {
    return err
}

for _, symbols := range accBalance {
    symbol := symbols.(map[string]interface{})
    free, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(symbol["free"].(string) , 64)
    locked, _ := strconv.ParseFloat(symbol["locked"].(string) , 64)
    coin := symbol.(string)     
}
```

При этом `accBalance` имеет такой вид:

```golang
map[message: result:map[BTC:map[available:0 freeze:0] ETH:map[available:0 freeze:0]] success:true]
```

Но возникает проблема с тем, как нормально обращаться к `symbol`, так как у него "**ключа**", а "**значение**" всегда меняется. Нужно сделать так, чтобы парсинг не зависел жестко от "**значения**".

А еще возникает проблема с тем, как правильно присваивать `coin` значение `symbol` типа `string`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно распрарсить хеш-таблицу, то её и используйте:

```golang
type BalancesResponse struct {
    Success bool   `json:"success"`
    Message string `json:"message"`

    Result map[string]AccBalance `json:"result"`
}

type AccBalance struct {
    Available string `json:"available"`
    Freeze    string `json:"freeze"`
}
```

*Playground*:
https://play.golang.org/p/pDGtGr146Ad.

Comment: А как мне обращаться к элементам Result? То есть как теперь войти в _range_ по элементам Result.

Comment: Странный вопрос.  https://play.golang.org/p/ounIy0imLxo.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответы!